# Runtime data validation for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, validation

TypeScript has no runtime check to ensure that loaded data matches the types. We currently use JSON schemas that we generate from our types with `typescript-json-schema` via a CLI and then validate in runtime with `ajv`. A great solution we thought until we found that it didn't play well with JS dates since dates are not part of JSON.

Does anyone have a solution for this? We use types not classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) library. You will only need to have one schema and you can use it to generate types & validate data using JSON Schema.

> Zod is a TypeScript-first schema declaration and validation library. I'm using the term "schema" to broadly refer to any data type/structure, from a simple string to a complex nested object.

Take a look at this example:

```
import * as z from 'zod'

const schema = z.object({
    stringValue: z.string(),
    numberValue: z.number(),
    dateValue: z.date()
})

type MyType = z.infer<typeof schema>
// type MyType = {
//     stringValue: string;
//     numberValue: number;
//     dateValue: Date;
// }

const data = schema.parse({
    stringValue: 'Hello',
    numberValue: 1,
    dateValue: new Date()
})
```

---

> <strike>The biggest issue with this library is that it doesn't work well when you need to transform data (e.g. you get the date as a string). It has an [open issue](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/100) regarding data transformation. Also, you can't generate JSON schema from zod instance (check [the issue](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/177)).</strike>

Zod 3 resolved [data transformation](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#transform)

Comment: Is there any library that does not have such issues and works easier with TS?

Comment: The new [zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) version resolved most of the issues and now works perfectly with typescript, so I suggest trying it!

Comment: Thanks for the update! I already started using Zod and is great 