# How to deserialize a JSON with validation in Typescript?

Tags: json, typescript, deserialization

Suppose I need to create an instance of `interface A { x: number, a: string}` from a JSON string `const str = {"x":0,"a":""}` in Typescript.

If the JSON does not contain the required properties `x` and `a` of the required types I would like to get an exception, e.g. `property "a" is missing` or `property "x" is not a number`.

I can parse the JSON string into an object `const obj = JSON.parse(str)` and check if `obj` contains properties `x` and `a` manually. I wonder whether there is a *better* way to create an instance of `A` from JSON *without* validating the properties of input JSON and their types manually.

What is the simplest way to deserialize a JSON to an instance of an interface *with* validation ?

Comment: You could try one of the approaches at this question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings` to get an array of keys and validate that they exist.  Not perfect since it doesn't validate types as well though.  Making an empty class that implements the interface, instantiating an instance, then iterating through its keys seems like the quickest fit.

Comment: Thanks. This solution looks complicated :(( I would not like to validate the keys manually. Too much boilerplate, I think.

Comment: I think the class-that-implements might not be too bad.  `interface MyInterface {a:string;b:string};  class MyInterfaceStub implements MyInterface {a:string="stub";b:string="stub"};  const keysToValidate = Object.keys(new MyInterfaceStub());`.  It's definitely not excellent (you basically have to declare stuff twice), but it should give you compile-time errors if you forget to update the implementing stub class, and lets you get at an automatically generated run-time array of the key names to check.  Also lets you assert `typeof objectToCheck[keyName] === typeof stubClassInstance[keyName]`

Comment: Are you trying to validate an object with some schema? Like what `yup` does?

Comment: @ArtHare Thanks again. Your solution looks fine. I will try it.

Comment: @c0m1t No, I don't use any schema. I did not know what `yup` is. Thanks for pointing me out. I will take a look.

Comment: duplicate of [Runtime data validation for TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65479057/runtime-data-validation-for-typescript) and [Generate JSON schema from typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939657/generate-json-schema-from-typescript)